# How to change the size of audio visualisers in ffmpeg?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I have this command in ffmpeg:

```
echo shell_exec("$ffmpeg  -i test.aiff -y -filter_complex '[0:a]showfreqs=s=1920x1080:mode=bar:ascale=log:fscale=lin:win_size=w1024:win_func=poisson:colors=blue,format=yuv420p[v]' -map '[v]' -map 0:a output2.mp4 2>&1");
```

I want to make it so that the video dimensions are still 1080p but the showfreqs graph is squashed and located near the bottom of the screen. How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create it in the smaller size and pad your way to 1080p.

```
ffmpeg  -i test.aiff -y -filter_complex 
    '[0:a]showfreqs=s=1920x300:mode=bar....colors=blue,
          pad=1920:1080:0:oh-ih,format=yuv420p[v]'
    -map '[v]' -map 0:a output2.mp4 2>&1
```

Comment: genius. Thanks :)

Comment: can you explain why you need yuv420 btw

Comment: It's the only pixel format commonly supported by players.